# how to get list of all available values in select (HTML) using flask

Tags: python, html, flask, html-select

I have a piece of html code where i use select and have a list of options the user can choose from.

```
<td>
    <select id="target" name="target">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

My python code:

```
listOfAllOptions = request.form.getlist('target')
```

The above code only gives the selected option. However, I want list of all the options available in the select.

> Expected output: ["1","2","3"]

Please help.

Comment: Is the selected list static? If so, then why not make the list in your python script and use it to populate the options on the HTML page. That way you don't need to ask the form for the options since you already have them in code.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i can only change the back end side so if possible please answer on how to do it on python. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) library:

$ pip install lxml

And the code:

```py
from lxml import html

html_string = """<td>
    <select id="target" name="target">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</td>
"""

dom_tree = html.fromstring(html_string)
options_lst = dom_tree.xpath("//option//text()")

print(options_lst)
```

output: ['1', '2', '3']